# Add common values from 2 List<String> to a new List without duplicates

Tags: apex

I have 2 list which I want to compare and add only the common values to a new List. I tried to loop over the first List and use the `.contains` on the second List and then tried to add to the third List but it is giving me a weird list instead of a list having the common values added. Here is my code snippet:

```
List<String> list1 = '2024/2025, 2025/2026';
List<String> list2 = '2024/2025, 2025/2026, 2026/2027';
List<String> list3 = new List<String>();

for(String str: list1){
 if(list2.contains(str)){
       list3.add(str);
   }
}
```

Expected Output:
(2024/2025, 2025/2026)

Actual Output:
(2024/2025, 2024/2025, 2025/2026, 2024/2025, 2025/2026)
[image]

Any other way to achieve the expected output?

Comment: Based on your code, the expected output should be `['2023/2024', '2024/2025']`

Comment: Hi @DerekF, there's a slight diff in the Lists which i edited now but i'm not getting the expected output, I'm getting the actual output

Comment: You should definitely take more care in the examples that you provide here. Inaccurate example code will tend to lead to inaccurate answers. If I take the code you've currently provided to us (and fix the obvious syntax errors in initializing list1 and list2), it produces the correct output. That means that your issue is somewhere in code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Also, brief note. While the `List` class does have a `.contains()` method, I don't generally recommend using it. That's because the method does a linear search through the list, and using it inside of a loop basically means you have a nested loop (and a runtime complexity of `O(N^2)`). It's not a big deal for short lists, but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: I wonder if we have an x/y problem on our hands here. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You should be taking advantage of `Set`s here, which has `removeAll()` and `retainAll()` methods.

e.g.

```java
Set<String> firstSet = new Set<String>{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
Set<String> secondSet = new Set<String>{'c', 'b', 'e'};

// retainAll() modifies the collection it is called on
// It also (unfortunately, in my eyes) returns a boolean instead of a Set
firstSet.retainAll(secondSet);

// Should output ['b', 'c']
// (or perhaps ['c', 'b'], since sets are unordered)
system.debug(firstSet);
```